# Two, almost identical lines of code with different results?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm learning how to do code for web development, and I have run into a problem. Two almost identical lines of code are giving me different results:

```
for(i=0; i<=lunarSpells.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(lunarSpells[i]).innerHTML =
    Math.ceil(xpLeft/document.getElementById(lunarSpells[i]+"XP").innerHTML);   
}
for(i=0; i<=standardSpells.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(standardSpells[i]).innerHTML =
    Math.ceil(xpLeft/document.getElementById(standardSpells[i]+"XP").innerHTML);    
}
```

Unsure of its importance, but the idea is to take an element from the array, find it in the document, and then fill in the table accordingly. Here are the arrays:

```
var lunarSpells = ["cureOther", "NPCContact", "curePlant", "monsterExamine", "bakePie", "cureMe", "TGMoonclan",
                            "TPMoonclan", "TGBarbarian", "superglass", "TPKhazard", "TGKhazard", "dream", "stringJewellery",
                            "statRestorePotShare", "statSpy", "TPBarbarian", "TPWaterbirth", "cureGroup", "TGWaterbirth", "humidify",
                            "hunterKit", "fertileSoil", "plankMake", "TPCatherby", "TGFishingGuild", "TGCatherby", 
                            "boostPotionShare", "TPIcePlateau", "energyTransfer", "healOther", "TGIcePlateau", "vengeanceOther",
                            "vengeance", "healGroup", "spellbookSwap", "magicImbue", "TPFishingGuild"]

var standardSpells = ["confuse", "sapphire", "weaken", "bananas", "curse", "lowAlch", "TPVarrock", "emerald", "TPLumbridge", "TPFalador", "TPHouse",
                                "superheat", "TPCamelot", "ruby", "TPArdougne", "highAlch", "earth", "water", "diamond", "TPWatchtower", 
                                "peaches", "TPTrollheim", "fire", "TPApe", "vulnerability", "air", "dragonstone", "enfeeble", "TOLumbridge", "stun", 
                                "TOFalador", "onyx", "TOCamelot"]
```

So my question, is WHY is the lunarspells variable working, while the standardspells variable is not? Any help is much appreciated, as I am still quite new to HTML and JS.

Comment: Any errors to show? Plus, you want to use `<`, not `<=` I think. Actually, that's probably why the code fails.

Comment: What's the expected and actual result?

Comment: what is/is not working?

Comment: what is `working` and `not working` in this context?

Comment: If `document.getElementById` can't find the element, it returns `null`, and you can't get/set things on it - it will fail with an exception. Are you sure there are elements with every single one of these `id`s?

Comment: The expected result is that (standardSpells[i]).innerHTML will be changed; which happens in the first for loop but not the second. Also, thanks @Paul, don't know why I put <=!

Comment: @Ian: unless there's an element with an ID of "undefinedXP", the last iteration of the first loop will definitely throw an exception. `<=` vs `<`.

Comment: I've noticed that the second for loop isn't even entered? Any suggestions as to why this may happen?

Comment: @DCoder That's very true, but that wasn't my point. PaulGrime seemed to already cover that. I'm talking about each element. I'm not sure how these arrays are generated, but if the 10th item in the array is for an `id` that doesn't exist, the loop will fail and stop there.

Comment: @zsherman PaulGrime already pointed out your problem. Your loops need to use `<`, not `<=`. The first loop will fail on the last iteration

Comment: Yeah, caught that just now @DCoder, thank you

Comment: Not that it's your problem, but you could also `parseInt` (or `parseFloat`) your innerHTML just to make sure you divide with a number

Comment: While that was a problem, it doesn't seem to be the only one. Any way I can help anyone help me?

Comment: Is there any reason your referencing data in the DOM? It wouldnt be much work to convert all your data to an Object for easy access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned:

```
xpLeft/document.getElementById(lunarSpells[i]+"XP").innerHTML
```

will fail if `document.getElementById("id_that_doesnt_exist")` evaluates to `null` (as `null.anything` is an error.

This will stop all further processing in the `<script>` block unless you avoid the error, or wrap in `try`/`catch`.

So your second loop won't get reached/executed.

Comment: Aha! While this didn't directly fix things, it did point me in the direction of my error. I had accidentally put two identical elements in the first array, throwing off the .length portion. Changing <= to < and removing that extra element fixed the issue. Thank you!